# I intend 2 dimensional kernal but layers made 3 dimensional kernal

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I was trying to classifying with mnist model, so change the shape of number image like
(pic_num,size,size,?(I don't know what this dimensional mean)
and to use the loss function with 'categorical_entropy', change the 1-dimensional label data as one-hot label data

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(28,28,1),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is my model and compiler.

When I do this code:

'''

```
history=model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_split=0.25,epochs=30,
batch_size=200,verbose=0,callbacks=[early_stopping_callback,checkpointer])
```

This is error code:

```
 ~ in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
 Shapes (200, 10, 2) and (200, 10) are incompatible
```

I'm trying to change the flatten layer position and change the train data and label shape but it all didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several corrections in your code . You can use this code for MNIST :

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.summary()
```

Output :

> ```
> Model: "sequential"
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 13, 13, 32)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 64)        18496     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1600)              0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1600)              0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                16010     
> =================================================================
> Total params: 34,826
> Trainable params: 34,826
> Non-trainable params: 0
> ____________________________________
> ```

```
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])
```

Final Output :

> Test loss: 0.023950600996613503

> Test accuracy: 0.9922000169754028